# Rails 5 previous or next post ONLY from certain tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a resource named posts, of which there are many. However, each post can have multiple tags. I want users to be able to go to the previous post and next post, ONLY from the tag that was selected. I have it working for all posts from the database in previous next, but when I click on a tag and it shows all the tags, prev/next doesn't adhere to what the tag is.

If I visit the url in association with the code defined in routes.rb,   `get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag`, it'll list all the tags in an index. I don't want this, I want a user to be able to click previous or next and only do so on posts that are associated with a tag.

**Note: I am using the friendly_id gem**

**controllers/posts_controller.rb**

```
  def index
    @posts = Post.all

    if params[:tag]
      @posts = Post.tagged_with(params[:tag])
    else
      @posts = Post.all
    end

  end
```

**models/post.rb**

```
# tags 
  acts_as_taggable # Alias for acts_as_taggable_on :tags

def next
    Post.where("id > ?", id).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
end

def prev
     Post.where("id < ?", id).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<%= link_to "← Previous Question", @post.prev, :class => 'button previous-question' %>

<%= link_to "Next Question →", @post.next, :class => 'button next-question' %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
 # TAGS
  get 'tags/:tag', to: 'posts#index', as: :tag
```

Comment: `but when I click on a tag and it shows all the tags` can you explain a litle more? where it will show all tags? can you add code for this?

Comment: I've updated the post @NarasimhaReddy

Comment: So when a tag is clicked and its associated posts are displayed, you want pagination for those list of posts?

Comment: @arjun Whenever a tag is clicked and it shows a list of associated posts, I would like for the user to click into any one of the posts and go backwards or forwards, but ONLY for that tag. (hence previous and next). I'm trying to make it so that the user can only see one at a time.

Answer (score 7):

I think you are going to have to pass around that `tag` parameter (although you should probably make it a helper method)

models/post.rb

```
def next tag
  Post.where("id > ?", id).tagged_with(tag).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
end

def prev tag
  Post.where("id < ?", id).tagged_with(tag).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first
end
```

show

```
<%= link_to "← Previous Question", post_path(@post.prev(current_tag).id, tag: current_tag), :class => 'button previous-question' %>

<%= link_to "Next Question →", post_path(@post.next(current_tag).id, tag: current_tag), :class => 'button next-question' %>
```

controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :current_tag

  #def show
  #def index

  private

  def current_tag
    params[:tag]
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more as to what's going on? Also.. I got this error. What is going on? Should there be a space between next and tag as you wrote it for the model.rb?

`ActionController::UrlGenerationError at /posts/1
No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"posts", :id=>nil, :tag=>nil}, possible unmatched constraints: [:id]`

Comment: There should be a space between next and tag, as it is an argument to the method. (You can put it in parenthesis if you desire, though that is not needed in ruby).  As for The error, I think I messed up in my implementation in the view. You need to pass the id to the url_helper (I think. let me edit it). However, I am not sure why the tag parameter is nil.

Comment: Basically,. what we are doing is passing the tag along each request as `current_tag` and then in either `next` or `post` we are re-evaluating the scope `tagged_with` with `current_tag` being the arguement.

Comment: Hey @Sean, I'm getting thsi error now: `NoMethodError at /posts/hello-world
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass` - I'm using `acts_as_taggable` and `friendly_id`

Comment: perhaps a `self.id` call is needed in the model. do you have the full stack trace of that error?

Answer (score 4):

You can put this in your controller then, `Post.where(["id < ?", id]).last` for previous and `Post.where(["id > ?", id]).first` this for next.

What you are trying to do is the job of the controller. You can extend those based on your sorting.

I also found [this gem](https://github.com/glebm/order_query). Would be much better for you to use.

Comment: This is only for the post, I have this functionality working already. What I want is previous or next depending on the tag.

Comment: What do you mean depending on the tag?

Comment: It's working fine if the user is in the posts controller clicking previous or next, because it's all in the database. 

However.. if a user clicks a certain tag, such as "fruits", it should only show posts tagged with "fruits" if the user clicks on "fruits" the tag. 

All the posts have tags, I just want to only show the relevant posts in the "previous and next button" if the user clicks on any tag. Sorry if it wasnt clear before

Answer (score 4):

Here is updated Sean's answer. It should work now. The problem appears when `prev` or `next` methods returning `nil`

models/post.rb

```
def next tag
  result = Post.where("id > ?", id).tagged_with(tag).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first

  result || very_first(tag)
end

def prev tag
  result = Post.where("id < ?", id).tagged_with(tag).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first

  result || very_last(tag)
end

def very_first tag
  Post.tagged_with(tag).order(id: :asc).limit(1).first
end

def very_last tag
  Post.tagged_with(tag).order(id: :asc).limit(1).last
end
```

show

```
<% if @post.prev(current_tag) %>
  <%= link_to "← Previous Question", post_path(@post.prev(current_tag).id, tag: current_tag), :class => 'button previous-question' %>
<% end %>

<% if @post.next(current_tag) %>
  <%= link_to "Next Question →", post_path(@post.next(current_tag).id, tag: current_tag), :class => 'button next-question' %>
<% end %>
```

controllers/posts_controller.rb

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  helper_method :current_tag

  #def show
  #def index

  private

  def current_tag
    params[:tag]
  end
end
```

P.S. sorry Sean, I can't comment on your answer, so I just copied and fixed it

Comment: NameError at /posts/testpost
undefined local variable or method `result' for #<Post:0x007fe1538eb9f8>

Comment: There's a typo in  Petr's answer, result is not initialized in `prev` method, look at the `next` method definition and do the same - `result = Post.where("id < ?", id).tagged_with(tag).order(id: :desc).limit(1).first`

Comment: By the way putting all these methods in the Post model itself is not a very good idea as time shows on large projects, better create some PostPresenter and move that code there

Comment: Thanks Bogdan. It fixed

Answer (score 3):

You can also take nested resources approach and change your routes like this:

```
resource :tag do
  resource :post
end
```

It should give you routes structure so that `/tags/:tag_id/posts` will be pointing to all the posts for a given tag, and `/tags/:tag_id/posts/:id` will be pointing to exact post (or question?) tagged with that tag.

Then in posts controller, you should add `before_filter :set_tag` like this

```
before_filer :set_tag

def set_tag
  @tag = Tag.find(params[:tag_id])
end
```

index action would look like this

```
 def index
    @posts = @tag.posts
 end
```

and will always show posts for that tag.

In the show action of posts controller you can get next and previous post links just like in the answers above.

You should also change all the post url helpers used in views to include current tag, e.g. `posts_path` -> `tag_posts_path(@tag)` where tag is current tag that was set in before_filter.

I highly recommend you not putting all those methods on model and create a presenter object for a post, e.g.

```
class PostPresenter
  attr_reader :post
  alias_method :current, :post

  def initialize(post)
    @post = post
    @repo = post.class
  end

  def next
    @repo.where('id > ?', post.id).first
  end

  def previous
    @repo.where('id < ?', post.id).first
  end
end
```

and

`@presenter = PostPresenter.new(@post)`

and a next post's link

```
<%= link_to "Next Question →", 
      tag_post_path(@presenter.next), 
      class: 'button next-question' if @presenter.next.present? %>
```